# why '12.3456'.match(/^\d+\.\d{2}$|\d{2}$/) got '56'

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to  use javascript let 12.3456  -> 12.34

i tried `'12.3456'.replace(/^\d+\.\d{2}$|\d{2}$/,"")` can do it

even i go to https://regex101.com/ but i don't understand why the reg exp can match '56'

please help me to understand it

Comment: This may help https://regexr.com/41qve

Comment: If this is about rounding numbers, maybe you want `parseFloat('12.3456').toFixed(2)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your regex `/^\d+.\d{2}$|\d{2}$/` matches either a number with **two** decimals (`^\d+.\d{2}$`) **or** (`|`) the last two digits (`\d{2}$`). Since the first doesn't match (your input has four decimals), the second alternation is matched, and replaced with the empty string.

```
12.3456
     ^^    matched by \d{2}$
```

replaced with empty string gives

```
12.34
```